# How to create a project from existing source?

Tags: asp.net, macos, visual-studio

I installed Visual Studio 2017 on my mac. Also i have a project that written ASP.NET core. But i couldn't find any option to create a project from existing code.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Create a project file in the directory containing the code, then add all code to the project?

Answer (score -1):

I figured out.

Basically i opened **.csproj** file on Visual Studio. So that created ***.sln** file for me.

**Tip**: If you want to add more projects into your solution, you can simply add after opened ***.sln** file.